# Require windows password to enter administration form in app

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-authentication

I have an app that contains configuration settings that should be changed only by a user that is part of the MyAdvancedUsers Active Directory group. This application is a C# .NET 4.0 desktop application (not a web application)

When the app is running with regular user permissions, is it possible to allow access to the configuration settings form by a member of the MyAdvancedUsers by having the advanced user enter his/her windows username and password combination?

Comment: This app is running as the current user? Unless you use those credentials to elevate the process (or better yet, start another process elevated), this really won't provide any security benefit, and will be easy enough to bypass via a number of means.

Comment: How do you have regular users login to the application?

Comment: @ne819 The app is installed on the machine for 'all users' and is simply launched from the start menu or a shortcut

Comment: @kitsune My plan is to make the text fields in the form read-only until an 'elevated permissions flag' in the form is set.  If someone from the MyAdvancedUsers groups provides their credentials through a login pop-up dialog box, I will set the flag and allow read/write access to the text boxes.  When the form is dismissed the permissions will be reverted to read-only

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer This will only provide negligible security. It's rather easy to inject commands into other windows, bypassing your security. To say nothing of hot patching the process, or even simply modifying the data directly (if the app is running as the current user, then any other process can really access the same data). If this is largely just intended to 'keep honest people honest', then it will work fine, but don't mistakenly believe it can resist even a mildly determined attacker.

Comment: @kisune Your point is valid.  For this particular app I don't expect any 'determined hackers'.  It is mostly to prevent inadvertent changes where inexperienced users may not know all the effects of a property that they are changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do this.  Create a `PrincipalContext` and call `ValidateCredentials()` on it, thusly:

```
bool ValidateCredentials(String domain, String user, String password) {
  using (PrincipalContext principal = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "THE DOMAIN GOES HERE")   
  {
    return principal.ValidateCredentials(user, password);
  }
}
```

Try [this site](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/11/21/usercredentialsdialog.aspx) for a good way to capture the credentials from the user.

@Kitsune: you do not need to elevate privledges just to validate a user's credentials.

Comment: I don't understand how 'domain' is used on an app that is installed on the users computer. What goes into the domain string?

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer: The [Windows domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain), I would presume.

Comment: @DanielPryden : Thanks for the clarification.  It is the domain that is at the bottom of the standard windows login dialog box.

Comment: @Kisune: I didn't know that is was possible for another app to change the data in one of my windows forms while the app was running in memory.  I'm not using a database -- do I still have a risk here?

Comment: @DarwinIcesurfer: While another app could poke data into your app, that makes your app no more or less vulnerable that every other application out there.  This is not something you need to worry about, just something good to be aware of.